# Pending tasks submitted to concurrent.futures

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, concurrency

I am using a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` to download files from urls.

Declaration:

```
media_download_manager = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
```

Whenever necessary, downloads are triggered with the following statement:

```
media_download_manager.map(download_media_job, urls)
```

where `download_media_job` is a method that handles downloading along with some prior checks; `urls` is a list of unique urls of files to download. But, since there are multiple threads to download files, I do not want to submit duplicate urls while calling `media_download_manager.map` at separate places.

How do I get the **list of pending tasks submitted to concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor** without explicitly maintaining a separate list?